# Java ByteBuffer -> [NSData bytes] to UInt16

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets, nsdata, memcpy

Good day to all.

I'm writing a client-server application based on sockets. Server is written with Java, client - with Objective-C on iOS SDK 7.

My server writes data to a connected socket with the next code:

```
//Socket client = new ...;
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
// send package
String message = "pings"; // package body
byte bodySize = (byte) message.length();
java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + 2 + 1 + bodySize);
buffer.putShort((short) 16); // package ID (2 bytes)
buffer.putShort((short) 7); // package header (2 bytes, bitmask options)
buffer.put(bodySize); // calculate & put body size in 5th byte (1 byte)
buffer.put(message.getBytes()); // put the message to buffer (+5 bytes)

out.write(buffer.array()); // write to stream
out.close(); // close stream
```

Then I'm trying to parse accepted NSData in Objective-C client. Here's the code:

```
- (UInt16)packageIdFromPackageHead:(NSData *)data {
    const void *bytes = [data bytes];
    UInt16 packageId;
    memcpy(&packageId, bytes + 0, 2); // get first 2 bytes, it must be short = 16
    return packageId;
}
```

But, in the "packageId" variable I have the value "4096". What is this? Where is my 16 decimal value?

Next, I'm trying to get the next value, "package header". I wrote the following code:

```
UInt16 header;
memcpy(&header, bytes + 2, 2); // skip first 2 bytes, copy next 2 bytes, must be short = 7
```

I got a huge value, 1792. Why? What is this number means? I tried several offsets, +2, +3 - nothing. I can't get a correct value.  I tried to use some conversion as

```
header = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(header);
```

or

```
header = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(header);
```

This leads to nothing - I got 0 every time after conversion.

Next, when I tried to get the 5th byte (it contains our message string length, you remember). Here's the code:

```
UInt8 bodySize;
memcpy(&bodySize, bytes + 4, 1); // get the 5th byte
```

I got the value

```
'\x05'
```

And it is correct.

I'm almost certain that the input NSData * value is correct. Here you can see the memory dump screenshot from Xcode:

[Debug mode. Input NSData * memory dump](http://piccy.info/view3/6516579/387eda1d3ca7bb32ca913dbe6d00585f/)

Where is a problem? In the server code? Or in my client reading code? Please help, I spent 2 days to find a solution and I still couldn't get it.

Comment: `memcpy(&packageId, bytes + 0, 2);` -- where do you get `bytes` from??

Comment: And if you NSLog the NSData object you will get a hex dump you can examine to determine what you received.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. Bytes is `const void *bytes = [data bytes]`. I fixed my question's description. Thanks.

Comment: After NSLog I got the following: `data: <00100007 05>` All bytes are correct... Why I can't get them?

Comment: Hint:  0x0700 is 1792.  (Use the hex conversion feature of your Mac calculator app.)

Comment: Wow... What's the... I tried to make data with offsets 0..4 (2 bytes each time) and get UInt16 from it. Here's the results: `offset 0 data <0329> UInt16 10499; offset 1 data <2900> UInt16 41; offset 2 data <0007> UInt16 1792; offset 3 data <0705> UInt16 1287` And... Why?! 10499 = 0x2903. 41 = 0x0029. 1792 = 0x0700... Two bytes reads in reverse order! Many thanks for your hint, but, can you explain WHY bytes reads in such way? How I should modify "memcpy" call to get bytes correct?

Comment: Look up "endianness".

Comment: (You were on the right track with your swap ops, but a 32 bit swap won't work on a 16 bit value very well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hot Licks!

Correct client code is:

```
const void *bytes = [data bytes];
UInt16 packageId; // 16-bit value
memcpy(&packageId, bytes + 0, 2); // copy first 2 bytes
packageId = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(packageId); // fix endianness for 16-bit value
return packageId; // now we got correct value
```

Or, and it's more convenient, modify Java code on the server with:

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + 2 + 1 + bodySize);
buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

After this modification the initial client code will work correctly without using CFSwapInt... functions.

Many-many thanks for your help!